# How we can add custom attribute in attribute form using observer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to add the new custom attribute on attribute form to select attribute set when creating an attribute.

I've checked an event in Magento '**adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_frontend_prepare_form**' but how we can use it in observer means addField code and what we will return on that?

Comment: Describe your requirement in more detail.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I want to add an attribute of Attribute set in which when we will create any attribute from admin UI then admin can select for which attribute set this is going to create got it?